# tslint error: Cannot find module 'redux/todo/actions'.ts(2307)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tslint

I have read many posts and articles about getting absolute imports working in a TypeScript project but I am not having a problem with that. My project is successfully working with absolute imports.

However, in VS Code, all absolute imports have the red squiggly underline with the message such as

```
Cannot find module 'redux/todo/actions'.ts(2307)
```

My assumption is that this is a tslint issue, but I have not been able to find resolution.

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src", // must be set to /src for abs imports
    "outDir": "build/dist",
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    // "rootDir": "src",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "build",
    "scripts",
    "acceptance-tests",
    "webpack",
    "jest",
    "src/setupTests.ts"
  ]
}
```

I have tried various configurations for "paths"

```
"paths": {
  "*": [
    "*",
   "redux/*"
    ]

},
```

and

```
"paths": {
  "redux*": ["/redux/*]
}
```

I also tried

```
"rootDir": "src"
```

Also went through the telint documentation but found nothing relevant.

Comment: This problem mysteriously went away. I'm wondering if VS Code wasn't indexing the projects files in the background. I'll leave the question unanswered for a couple of days and report back on it.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a TSLint issue. This is a TypeScript issue. TSLint adds static analysis ("linting") on top of the TypeScript language & services. Your error is from TypeScript saying it can't find a file/module.

It's hard to help more concretely without code samples, but since you mentioned the error went array, hooray!

For future reference, restarting the VS Code window (Ctrl/Cmd + Shift + P > Reload Window) generally gets rid of these complaints.